# Como desabilitar ARC para apenas alguns arquivos do projeto?

Tags: ios, arc

Tenho um projeto utilizando ARC mas gostaria de adicionar arquivos que não estão usando ARC. É possível fazer isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sim, é possível desabilitar o ARC apenas para alguns arquivos adicionando a flag de compilação `-fno-objc-arc` neles.

Você adiciona flags de compilação em Targets -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources. Clique duas vezes na coluna da direita em *Compiler Flags*. Você também pode adicionar em diversos arquivos clicando <kbd>⌘</kbd>, selecionando eles e apertando enter para abrir o diálogo de edição de flags.

[image: Exemplo]
<sub>**Nota:** baseada [nessa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646052/how-can-i-disable-arc-for-a-single-file-in-a-project?rq=1) pergunta do SO</sub>

**Atenção:** Veja mais sobre misturar ARC e não ARC nessa pergunta do SO: [Disable Automatic Reference Counting for Some Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448874/disable-automatic-reference-counting-for-some-files)